# Why do I have to code 'equal' twice when drawing an ellipse?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I had to draw an ellipse and used the following program, which gives me the expected results.

In the last part, I used `ax.set_aspect('equal')` and I noticed that I had also to use `plt.axis('equal')` : if I cancel this last instruction, I get just a box, but void of any ellipse...

I thought that using `ax.set_aspect('equal')` alone, would be sufficient, but it's not. I don't understand why. I may have some inconsistencies in the `plot` program, but I don't see where. I would appreciate your help.

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
sqrt = np.sqrt
atan = np.arctan
degrees = np.degrees
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

# Ellipse general equation's coefficients
A = 1 ; B = -1.25 ; C = 1.625 ; D = 1.875 ; E = 1.5 ; F = -2

# Previous personal calculations
det_M2 = (4*A*C - B**2) / 4
det_M3 = (B*D*E - (A*(E**2) + C*(D**2)) - (B**2 - 4*A*C)*F) / 4
xc = (B*E - 2*C*D) / (4*det_M2)
yc = (B*D - 2*A*E) / (4*det_M2)
center = [xc, yc]
theta = atan(B/(A-C)) / 2
lambda_plus = (A+C)/2 + sqrt(((A+C)/2)**2 - det_M2)
lambda_minus = (A+C)/2 - sqrt(((A+C)/2)**2 - det_M2)
a = sqrt(2)/2 * sqrt(-lambda_plus * det_M3) / det_M2
b = sqrt(2)/2 * sqrt(-lambda_minus * det_M3) / det_M2

# Plot
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=center, 
                  width=2 * a, 
                  height=2 * b, 
                  angle=degrees(theta), 
                  edgecolor='red', 
                  linestyle='-', linewidth=2, fill=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

ax.add_patch(ellipse)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Ellipse')
ax.legend()
ax.grid(False)
             
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')` sets the aspect ratio of the plot to be equal, meaning one unit on the x-axis is equal to one unit on the y-axis within the axes' bounding box ('box'), while `plt.axis('equal')` ensures that the plotting area (the axes limits) is adjusted so that the ratio of the tick unit on the x-axis is the same as the tick unit on the y-axis. But, you could actually do this in another way by autoscaling:

```
sqrt = np.sqrt
atan = np.arctan
degrees = np.degrees
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

A = 1 ; B = -1.25 ; C = 1.625 ; D = 1.875 ; E = 1.5 ; F = -2

det_M2 = (4*A*C - B**2) / 4
det_M3 = (B*D*E - (A*(E**2) + C*(D**2)) - (B**2 - 4*A*C)*F) / 4
xc = (B*E - 2*C*D) / (4*det_M2)
yc = (B*D - 2*A*E) / (4*det_M2)
center = [xc, yc]
theta = atan(B/(A-C)) / 2
lambda_plus = (A+C)/2 + sqrt(((A+C)/2)**2 - det_M2)
lambda_minus = (A+C)/2 - sqrt(((A+C)/2)**2 - det_M2)
a = sqrt(2)/2 * sqrt(-lambda_plus * det_M3) / det_M2
b = sqrt(2)/2 * sqrt(-lambda_minus * det_M3) / det_M2

ellipse = Ellipse(xy=center, 
                  width=2 * a, 
                  height=2 * b, 
                  angle=degrees(theta), 
                  edgecolor='red', 
                  linestyle='-', linewidth=2, fill=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=center, width=2*a, height=2*b, angle=np.degrees(theta),
                  edgecolor='red', fill=False, linewidth=2, linestyle='-')

ax.add_patch(ellipse)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.relim()  
ax.autoscale_view()  
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Ellipse')

plt.show()
```

which gives you

[image]